# Add Values together Based on Criteria in Another Column

Tags: r

I am trying to sum up the values in certain columns based on the player's birth state.

Using the Lahman package in R, I have the following code:

```
library(Lahman)
#filter data frames by year
#collegeInfo <- CollegePlaying %>% filter(yearID >= 1999) #to do later
battingInfo <- Batting %>% filter(yearID >= 1999)

total <- merge(battingInfo,People,by="playerID")
totalN <- total[,-c(24,25,28:47)]

filterByState <- totalN %>% group_by(birthState) %>% summarise(players = length(birthState)) 
filterByGame <- totalN %>% group_by(birthState) %>% summarise(gamesPlayed = length(G))
```

In these above two, I am trying to see how many games (G) and number 
of DIFFERENT players that played in each state. However, they both return the same values for games played and number of players i.e. birthState 'AB' has a value of 11 games played and also 11 players which should not happen. Both of these values are wrong. There were 11 seasons that a player from birthstate 'AB' played, but of those 11 seasons, only 4 are from different playerIDs. So # of players from birthstate 'AB' should be 4, and adding their games played (G) it should equal 232 G. (4 players and 232 G is correct based off data from totalN)

```
newMerge <- merge(totalN, filterByState, by="birthState")
newTest <- newMerge %>% group_by(birthState) %>% summarise_at(vars(G, AB, R, H, X2B, X3B, HR, RBI, SB, CS, BB,
                                                                   SO, IBB, HBP, SH, SF, GIDP), sum, na.rm =  TRUE)
```

This now merges everything, and when you look at birthstate 'AB' it now has 232 games played which is correct, but doesn't show the number of players.

If possible I'd like to see the number of games and DIFFERENT players for each state in the function newTest, with the correct numbers (birthState 'AB' should have 4 players and the updated number that comes from newTest for games played is 232.

For example, the table looks something like this:

```
playerID  birthState     Hits Season GamesPlayed
player 1     NJ           17    2009      10
player 1     NJ           10    2010      20
player 2     NJ           20    2009      30
player 3     CA           45    2009      40
player 4     TX           87    2009      50
player 5     CA           50    2009      60
player 6  Outside USA     30    2009      70
```

And I'd like it to look like this (adding up all the hits for each state):

```
birthState      hits             Players    GamesPlayed
    NJ           47 (17+20+10)      2           60 (10+20+30)
    CA           95 (45+50)         2           100 (40+60)
    TX           87                 1           50
  Outside        30                 1           70
```

Comment: Try `filterbyState1 %>% group_by(birthState) %>% summarise(hits = sum(Hits))`

Comment: I didn't find the `Hits` column in`filterbyState1`.  Do you need to sum up columns rowwise and then do the group by sum? `filterbyState1 %>% transmute(birthState, Hits = select(., G:GIDP) %>% reduce(`+`)) %>% group_by(birthState) %>% summarise(hits = sum(Hits))`

Comment: @akrun hits is "H". I just didn't use the abbreviation sorry

Comment: I can't reproduce your update.  it is not showing totalN

Comment: @akrun sorry it's now updated with totalN - I deleted it by accident when I previously updated

Comment: Do you need `newMerge %>% group_by(birthState) %>% summarise(hits = sum(H), Playerss = n_distinct(playerID))`

Comment: @akrun yes thank you that fixed it! Also, do you know is there a way I can add all the Outside USA (Aichi, Belfast, etc.) states into one row so I have players, games, hits, etc. on all 50 states, and then all foreign states are summed into one row as well?

Comment: No worries. I will post in a new post... and just upvoted the solutions that helped!

Comment: It's okay.  I will answer it here

Comment: You can do `newMerge %>%  group_by(bithState = case_when(!birthState %in% state.abb ~ "Other", TRUE ~ birthState)) %>% summarise(hits = sum(H), Playerss = n_distinct(playerID))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a `group_by` `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
out <- filterbyState1 %>% 
          group_by(birthState) %>%
          summarise(hits = sum(H))
```

For multiple columns `sum` use `summarise_at`

```
filterbyState1 %>%
     group_by(birthState) %>%
     summarise_at(vars(H, players, AB, G), sum, na.rm =  TRUE)
```

Comment: If I wanted to add other columns to out, so I can see the hits, number of players, AB, and G would it look like this: out <- filterbyState1 %>% 
          group_by(birthState) %>%
          summarise(hits = sum(H)) %>% summarise(players = sum(players)) %>% summarise(ab = sum(AB)) %>% summarise(games = sum(G))